# If $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ (where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$), then are $H$ and $K$ normal in $HK$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> If $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ (where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$), then are $H$ and $K$ normal in $HK$?

I know that:

- for $HK$ to be a subgroup, it's not necessary that $H$ and $K$ be normal in $G$.
- $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $HK=KH$.
- not normal in $G$ does not mean not normal in any subgroup of $G$.

But I do not have any idea about the question in the title.

Comment: You did not provide any context.

Comment: Let $G$ be the group of the square. Let $H$ be the group generated by the horizontal flip, let $K$ be the group of rotations. Then $HK=G$, and $H$ is not normal in $G$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: This Q should be closed but my now deleted answer shows that one can take a triangle instead of the square.

Comment: @Gerry 
Can you provide an example where HK is not the whole group, I mean where HK is a proper subgroup of G ?

Comment: @markvs, yes, and my comment shows that one can take a square instead of a triangle.

Comment: Well, Esha, I suppose you could take my example but just let $G$ be a group containing the group of the square, say, the direct sum of the group of the square and any nontrivial group.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: My answer was posted earlier than your comment and $3<4$.

Comment: @markvs, yes, and $4>3$.

Comment: So, Esha, how about my example?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the (nondirect) internal semidirect product $G=H\rtimes K$. We have $G=HK$, $H\unlhd G$, $H\cap K=\{e\}$, and $K\le G$, but $K\not\unlhd HK=G$.

Comment: You should not answer questions without context. You should vote to close.

Comment: But there is context, @markvs; the OP listed relevant information they know.

Comment: OK, I have undeleted my answer. It was posted 3 minutes prior to yours.

Comment: @markvs Take it easy!  Be sure that the OP needs to reflect about this answer if he(she) wants to learn. :-)

Comment: @markvs What do I need to add more to my question for it to be not considered for closing down?

Comment: Nothing. It's fine as it is, @Esha.

Comment: @Esha: You should not post questions without context: what did you try?, what do you know?, where are the difficulties?, etc. In the case of this Q, you needed to add what did you try. The phrase that you "do not have any idea" means that you want others to solve the homework for you. You are lucky that the Q was not closed immediately.

Comment: I did try to prove that the result is true like we do for proving that a subgroup is normal in G, but could not. And indeed it cannot be proved as the statement is not true in general as mentioned in the answers. Since my attempt did not have any fruitful result , that's why I didn't add it in the question.

Comment: @Shaun 
In all the answers, the examples considered turn out to give HK=G, but can you provide an example where HK is not the whole group, I mean where HK is a proper subgroup of G ?

Comment: I'm not sure, @Esha, but I would start by looking at groups such as $G=L\rtimes (H\rtimes K)$ for nontrivial $L$, since then $HK\neq G$.

Comment: @Shaun Actually I have not studied semidirect product yet. That's why I am not able to understand your example properly.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question, @Esha, with that added detail (and a link to this question). We have answered the question correctly as it was asked originally.

Answer (score 0):

No. $S_3$ is a product of the subgroup of order $3$ and a subgroup of order $2$, only one of them is normal.

One can easily construct an example where none of the subgroups is normal.

Comment: Can you provide an example where HK is not the whole group, I mean where HK is a proper subgroup of G ?

Comment: That is trivial: $S_3\times C_2$. To make sure that none of $H,K$ is normal is harder.