# If $HK$ is a subgroup but not equal to $G$ (where $H,K<G$), then are $H$ and $K$ normal in $HK$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

I have asked  a very similar question already and many have answered it also.

[If $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ (where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$), then are $H$ and $K$ normal in $HK$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4352674/583398)

But all the answers include trivial examples where HK becomes the whole group and one answers gives and example of semidirect product. But I am a newbie on this topic and only know a handful of things like external direct product, internal direct product. So, it would be helpful if one can provide example using these concepts only and a non trivial one where $HK$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Isn't Gerry already told you how to find that in this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352674/if-hk-is-a-subgroup-of-g-where-h-and-k-are-subgroups-of-g-then-are#comment9085564_4352674)?

Comment: If you know an example with $HK=G$, then you should be able to use it to construct an example with the same $H$ and $K$ and $HK$, but $HK$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. (Hint: take a direct product.)

Comment: Please don't just post a new question with an addendum. So you should just edit the post and add the clarifications, not post anew.

Comment: [This is my fault, @ArturoMagidin.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352674/if-hk-is-a-subgroup-of-g-where-h-and-k-are-subgroups-of-g-then-are#comment9085559_4352678)